# Module build failed due to ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuetify.js, node-modules

Below is the error I am getting on _users_filters.vue file. If I remove the entire code inside v-menu then I dont get any error so error is somewhere in this piece of code. Please help me find it. I am using vue 2.5.18 and vuetify 2.3.10 . I have added the vue-template-compiler but it didn't fix the issue.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-303d5f63","hasScoped":false,"buble":{"transforms":{}}}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./app/javascript/views/users/_users_filters.vue
Module build failed: Error
    at Node.transpile (/Users/Documents/weather/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:12676:11)
    at /Users/Documents/weather/node_modules/vue-template-es2015-compiler/buble.js:5864:59
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>:null:null)
```

_user_filters.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-toolbar id="filter">
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md1>
          <v-menu offset-y attach="#user-filter">
           <template v-slot:activator="{ on: menu, attrs }">
            <div class="dropdown" v-bind="attrs" v-on="{ ...menu }">User</div>
            <v-list id="user-filter">
             <template v-for="search_user in search_users">
              <v-list-tile @click="filterUsers({user: search_user})">
               <v-list-tile-title>{{ search_user.name }}</v-list-tile-title>
              </v-list-tile>
             </template>
            </v-list>
           </template>
          </v-menu>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-toolbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data: () => ({
    search_users: []
  }),
  created: function() {
    this.fetchSearchUsers();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchSearchUsers() {
      this.$axios.get('/users/search_users.json')
      .then(response => {
        this.search_users = response.data.search_users;
      });
    },
    
    filterLawyers() {
      console.log("Filtering")
      
    },
   }
 };
</script>
```

Comment: `template` and `div` elements following the `v-menu` are missing closing tags...

Comment: @MichalLevý sorry about that. It just happened while pasting the code on stackoverflow. But the issue is still there.